# Ola Hallengren - DatabaseBackup SQL Version - Backup to Azure requirements

Tags: sql-server-2012, ola-hallengren

I see that the DatabaseBackup requires SQL Server 2012 SP1 CU2 (11.03339). I have a Server using SP1 (11.0.3000), and I have verified Backing up to azure blob storage does work.

Is there a reason the Hallengren scripts require CU2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Microsoft's [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/sql-server-backup-and-restore-with-microsoft-azure-blob-storage-service):

> **Manage your backups to Microsoft Azure:** Using the same methods used to
>   backup to DISK and TAPE, you can now back up to Microsoft Azure
>   storage by specifying URL as the backup destination. You can use this
>   feature to manually backup or configure your own backup strategy like
>   you would for a local storage or other off-site options. This feature
>   is also referred to as SQL Server Backup to URL. For more information,
>   see SQL Server Backup to URL. **This feature is available in SQL Server
>   2012 SP1 CU2 or later.** This feature has been enhanced in SQL Server
>   2016 (13.x) to provide increased performance and functionality through
>   the use of block blobs, Shared Access Signatures, and striping.